# What kind of software and hardware do I need if I want to make a video streaming application?

Tags: video-streaming, hardware

I want to set up a stream server to broadcast video streams to clients. I know I probably need a RTMP server + some multicast hardware equipment. But I have no idea where to start, can someone help out here?

Comment: Feels like a [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) question and, as written, it's a bit too broad.